# NEW to MYSQL, INSERT INTO 'Table' Syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create some tables and populate them with dummy data and i've come across this problem that's making me scratch my head to no end as i don't understand it.

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `DRIVER` (
  `dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `dr_title` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `dr_fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dr_lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dr_DOB` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dr_licenceNo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dr_phone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `dr_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dr_ID`));

CREATE TABLE `VEHICLE` (
  `veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `veh_reg` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `veh_make` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `veh_model` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `veh_mileage` INT NOT NULL,
  `veh_MOTdate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `veh_servicedate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`veh_ID`));

CREATE TABLE `DELIVERY` (
  `del_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `del_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `del_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `VEHICLE_veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DRIVER_dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1_idx` (`DRIVER_dr_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_VEHICLE1_idx` (`VEHICLE_veh_ID` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`del_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_VEHICLE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VEHICLE_veh_ID`)
    REFERENCES `VEHICLE` (`veh_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DRIVER_dr_ID`)
    REFERENCES `DRIVER` (`dr_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

INSERT INTO DELIVERY(del_ID, del_date, del time, VEHICLE_veh_ID, DRIVER_dr_ID) VALUES
(01, '2016-02-06', '09:30:00', 03, 05),
(02, '2016-02-06', '09:30:00', 01, 02),
(03, '2016-02-07', '09:30:00', 02, 03),
(04, '2016-02-07', '09:30:00', 04, 01),
(05, '2016-02-07', '09:30:00', 10, 04),
(06, '2016-02-08', '09:30:00', 07, 01),
(07, '2016-02-08', '09:30:00', 08, 02),
(08, '2016-02-08', '09:30:00', 09, 03),
(09, '2016-02-08', '09:30:00', 02, 04),
(10, '2016-02-09', '09:30:00', 03, 05);
```

I inserted data into DRIVER and VEHICLE with no issues but when i try to insert data into DELIVERY i get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'time, VEHICLE_veh_ID, DRIVER_dr_ID) VALUES (01,
>   '2016-02-06', '09:30:00', 03, 05') at line 1

I'm using the same insert pattern that i've used for previous tables and the values match their corresponding types. I keep going through it over and over again and i can't see what i've done wrong. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: in your insert statement you have `del time` without `_`

Comment: little introspection would give you that `del time` is missing `_`

Comment: The error message tells you the exact spot ;)

Comment: It looks fine for me; which mysql server are you using?

Comment: This question closes as a Typo

Answer (score 1):

```
 del time
```

Should be one word. You wrote "del_time" when you created the table.